# Как правильно пользоваться классами в php?

Tags: php

Изучаю работу функций, решил сделать некое API для своего движка.
Вот так выглядит сама функция:

```
class le {

public function query($sql, $params)
{
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}

}
```

Теперь пытаюсь вызвать функцию в классе:

```
$engine = new le;
$banned = $engine->query("SELECT * FROM `bans` WHERE ip = ?", array(
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

И тут функции query нужно значение $db, которое должно быть таким:

```
$db   = new PDO('mysql:host='.$set['db']['host'].';dbname='.$set['db']['name'].';charset=utf8',$set['db']['user'],$set['db']['pass']);
```

Мне интересно, можно ли как-то при вызове функции new le; хранить переменную в самом классе? Примерно как-то так:

```
class le {
$db   = new PDO('mysql:host='.$set['db']['host'].';dbname='.$set['db']['name'].';charset=utf8',$set['db']['user'],$set['db']['pass']);
public function query($sql, $params)
{
    global $db;
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}

}
```

Однако данный код вызывает ошибку по типу:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$set' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php on line 4
```

Можете показать, как надо записывать такие переменные в классы?

UPD. Как я понял надо писать что-то типо того:

```
class le {

function __construct() {
$set  = json_decode(file_get_contents('engine/settings.json'), true);
$lang = json_decode(file_get_contents('engine/languages/'.$set['ui']['language'].'.json'), true);
$tpl  = unserialize(file_get_contents('engine/templates/'.$set['ui']['template'].'.serialize'));
$db   = new PDO('mysql:host='.$set['db']['host'].';dbname='.$set['db']['name'].';charset=utf8',$set['db']['user'],$set['db']['pass']);
}

public function query($sql, $params)
{
    $query = $this->$db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}
....


Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot access empty property in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php:13 Stack trace: #0 C:\servers\WWW\index.php(5): le->query('SELECT * FROM `...', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\servers\WWW\engine\engine.php on line 13
```

Comment: Использовать конструктор?

Comment: почему `global` то, если вы переменную членом класса сделали? `$this->db`

Comment: а `$set` - кто такой и откуда?

Comment: .....`$this->db`  + поле класса  `private $db = null` и другие тоже

Comment: По факту он = object(PDO)#2 (0) { }
А в функции выдается null 
Писал как вы: $this->db

Comment: @user272078 `По факту он = object(PDO)#2 (0) { } ` - а где этот факт был установлен?

Comment: еще бы при создании все это вписывать в `$this->db`, `$this->set`, `$this->lang` и так далее. и объявить их в классе в принципе

Comment: @user272078 обращение к полям класса через `$this->`. Соответственно класть данные надо в переменные через `$this->` и также считывать....и надо не забыть еще объявить в классе...те поля, которые будут использоваться

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам, спасибо за подсказки по поводу $this.

```
<?php
class le {

public function __construct()
{
$this->set  = json_decode(file_get_contents('engine/settings.json'), true);
$this->lang = json_decode(file_get_contents('engine/languages/'.$this->set['ui']['language'].'.json'), true);
$this->tpl  = unserialize(file_get_contents('engine/templates/'.$this->set['ui']['template'].'.serialize'));
$this->db   = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->set['db']['host'].';dbname='.$this->set['db']['name'].';charset=utf8',$this->set['db']['user'],$this->set['db']['pass']);
}

public function query($sql, $params)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($params);
    return $query;
}

public function ndate($a)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');
    $ndate = date('d.m.Y', $a);
    $ndate_time = date('H:i', $a);
    $ndate_exp = explode('.', $ndate);
    $nmonth = array(
        1 => 'янв',
        2 => 'фев',
        3 => 'мар',
        4 => 'апр',
        5 => 'мая',
        6 => 'июн',
        7 => 'июл',
        8 => 'авг',
        9 => 'сен',
        10 => 'окт',
        11 => 'ноя',
        12 => 'дек'
    );
    foreach($nmonth as $key => $value)
    if ($key == intval($ndate_exp[1])) $nmonth_name = $value;
    if ($ndate == date('d.m.Y')) return 'сегодня в ' . $ndate_time;
    elseif ($ndate == date('d.m.Y', strtotime('-1 day'))) return 'вчера в ' . $ndate_time;
    else return $ndate_exp[0] . ' ' . $nmonth_name . ' ' . $ndate_exp[2] . ' в ' . $ndate_time;
}

public function views($value)
{
    if ($value >= 1000) return round($value / 1000, 1).'K';
    else return $value;
}

public function json($url)
{
$cURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Accept: application/json'
));
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
return json_decode($result, true);
}

public function cache($function, $content) {
if (is_null($content)) {
$cache = $this->query('SELECT expires FROM cache WHERE function = ?',array($function))->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)['expires'];
if (is_null($cache)) {
$this->query('INSERT INTO `cache`(`function`, `expires`) VALUES (?,?)',array($function, time() - $set['int']['cache_time']));
return time() - $set['int']['cache_time'];
}
else return $cache;
}
else if (!is_null($content)) {
file_put_contents('engine/cache/'.$function.'.html', $content);
$this->query('UPDATE `cache` SET `expires`= ? WHERE function = ?',array(time() + $set['int']['cache_time'], $function));
}
}
}
?>
```